# Bulk Inventory Update in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, inventory-management

Do you have any suggestions on how can I update the product inventory in Prestashop using csv file? As I've checked the Prestahop's Admin Panel, I can't figure out how does the prestashop works on inventory files. Do I need to install module? Please suggest.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CSV file that excel doesn't really like(because it uses semicolons(;) instead of commas i think).  It's fairly in depth, and I haven't tried it yet.

I found the template in the back office under 'ADVANCED PARAMETERS' -> 'CSV Import'.  You will find sample CSV files there along with the acceptable fields.

I am referring to Prestashop 1.6.0.14 (current version as of today)

Comment: Got it, but the product's csv import contains limited fields only. Category field is separated. Do you have any suggestions?